# Copying files to Remote sever gives configuration error?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, server

In my program I am trying to copy files from a local folder to a folder on the remote server . But i get the error :

Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'The user name or password is incorrect.
'

aspx.cs code:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void MoveImages(string imageData)
    {
        string fileName = "";
        // get computer name

        string clientMachineName;
        clientMachineName = Dns.GetHostName();
        string computerName = clientMachineName.Split('-').First();

        // get download location

        string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
        string sourcePath = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");


        string pathstring = @"\\servername\shared folder";



        string cls = HttpContext.Current.Session["class"].ToString().Trim();
        string sub = HttpContext.Current.Session["subject"].ToString().Trim();
        string targetPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathstring, cls);
        string pathstring1 = targetPath;
        string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
        string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathstring1, sub);


        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
        {

            string[] jpg = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.jpg");
            string[] png = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.png");
            string[] files = jpg.Concat(png).ToArray();

            // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
            foreach (string s in files)
            {
                // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                if (s.Length > 0)
                {
                    fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(s);
                    sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);

                    destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(destFile, fileName);
                    if (File.Exists(destFile))
                    {
                        File.Delete(sourceFile);

                    }
                    else
                    {


                       File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile);

                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

web.config :

```
    <system.web>

    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
  <identity impersonate="true" userName="servrdomain\ADMINISTRATOR" 
   password="pswrd"/>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="someustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
```

What am I doing wrong?

FYI:
The path to the shared folder on the remote server is like :
E:\parentfolder\sharedfolder

In properties of the shared folder the network path is given as :\\servername\sharedfolder

Can anyone tell what should be the correct format of the pathstring:
@"\servername\shared folder" or  @"\servername\E$\parentfolder\shared folder" ?

shared file config is shared with everyone and all permissions granted.

Comment: i have tried many formats but the error persists..what is wrong here?

Comment: And you are sure that `domain\username` and `password` are correct and that windows authentication is enabled? If this site is running on IIS you need to have the `Windows Authentication` feature installed and enabled.

Comment: you mean the authentication under the IIS tab on the IIS manager on the remote server?

Comment: On the machine that is running the application.

Comment: Is the development environment running under IIS?

Comment: yes ..its running on IIS

Comment: And is the window authentication feature installed and enabled on your IIS?

Comment: I just checked ..It wasnt, but now i have enabled it ..Let me check now